# How to fetch data from mysql and display on Front page?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've created an admin panel for blog and everthing is working fine in admin panel, can read data and display.

but i want to show the blog data on front end. so I've created an another model and controller. but when i'm trying to publish content sometimes it'll shows me an error 500 or error 404.

Here is my controller -

```
  public function viewBlog(){
      $query = $this->MainModel->readBlogs();
      $data['BLOGS'] = null;
      if($query){
       $data['BLOGS'] =  $query;
      }
      $this->load->view('nulearnFront/blog', $data);
            $this->load->view('nulearnFront/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('nulearnFront/footer', $data);
     }
```

Here is my Model-

```
function readBlogs(){
  $this->db->select("btitle,sdesc");
  $this->db->from('blog');
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result();
 }
```

i've already googled a lot but i'm still trying to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my issue, I used belowe codes in controller-

```
function blog(){ 
        $blog['blog'] = $this->auth_model->readBlogs();
        $this->load->view('nulearnFront/header');
        $this->load->view('nulearnFront/blog', $blog);
        $this->load->view('nulearnFront/footer');
 }
```

and modified my model code like-

```
 function readBlogs(){
    $q="SELECT * from blog "; 
    $query=$this->db->query($q);
    return $query->result_array();
   }
```